# Find number of people given a set of ratios

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ratio

I've been asked this question:

> A luna park with 3 attractions had its people buying tickets for the attractions in the following ratio: 6:5:12 in 2001. There have been 200 more people in 2002 and the ratio was 7:2:5. The number of people in 2002 that visited the third attraction is 2000. How many people visited the first attraction in 2001?

I tried to solve this as follows but the "ratio" notation confuses me so I'm not sure I did it right: $x$ is the number of people visiting the first attraction in 2001

$ (x + \frac{x}{6}5 + \frac{x}{6}12) + 200 = 2000 + \frac{2000}{5}2 + \frac{2000}{5}7$

Is this the right approach or am I getting this wrong? I don't have a clearer text so I can't be more specific than this unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

If the total number of people is $x$, and they visited the attractions in the ratio $6:5:12$, then the first attraction was visited by $\frac{6}{6+5+12}\cdot x$ people, the second one was visited by $\frac{5}{6+5+12}\cdot x$ and the third was visited by $\frac{12}{6+5+12}\cdot x$ people.

Now, you can set the same equations up for the second year, only replace $x$ (which is the number of people in year $2001$) with $y$ (the number of people in the year $2002$).

Of course, the equation connecting $x$ and $y$ should be clear.

Comment: I thought of summing up the ratio numbers but then I wondered: what if some of the people that visited the first attraction also visited the second one? I'm a bit confused by this problem

Comment: @Dean It does not matter. $x$ is the total number of VISITS, actually. So for example, if $3$ people visited attraction $1$, $5$ people visited attraction $2$, and $7$ people visited attraction $3$, then the visit ratio is $3:5:7$, no matter if there was in reality only *one* person doing all $15$ visits.

Comment: Uhm.. $6x/23 + 5x/23 + 12x/23 = (x+200)7/14 + (x+200)2/14 + (x+200)5/14$.. this is not possible to solve. Did I read your answer wrong?

Comment: @Dean This is not possible to solve because the equation makes no sense. There is no reason to sum the number of visits. What you need to do is to find the number of visits of the first attraction in $2001$. What you **know** is the number of visits of the third attraction in $2002$. You need to use that knowledge. Try to think about what equation you can write to describe the sentence "The number of visits of the third attraction is $2000$".

Comment: Got it: $2000=y5/14$ where $y$ is the number of visits in 2002. Then I calculate $y6/23$ and I get 1408.69. That is also my result as I posted in the question although this reasoning makes more sense. I suppose this is correct.

Comment: @Dean The error you made is very typical for a beginner in such things, so here is some general advice: any time you write an equation, ask yourself: *Why is this equation correct*? If you cannot answer that question, don't write it.

Comment: @Dean Why would you calculate $\frac{6y}{23}$ when the number of visits in $2001$ is $x$, not $y$?

Comment: sorry I missed a passage: y is the number of visits in 2002. Then I **subtract** 200 from it and do that last passage: $6(y-200)/23$ to find people who visited the first attraction in 2001.

Comment: @Dean Correct! Well done!